# C# OOP Task problems

Tags: c#, oop

OK. I've managed to compress everything to 2 questions:

1/ Is the public enum supposed to be in the class or outside of it? I think they both worked but is there any good practice about it?

2/ I don't understand how to set up a constructor which has an object from another class. See comment at the bottom "Main" class.

GSM CLASS:

```
using System.Text;

class GSM
{
   public string model;
   public string manufacturer;
   public decimal price;
   public string owner;

    Battery battery = new Battery("Nokia", 7, 5);
    Display display = new Display(12.5, 3);

    // CONSTRUCTORS:
    public GSM(string model, string manufacturer, decimal price, string owner)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.price = price;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public GSM(string model, string manufacturer, decimal price, string owner, Battery battery, Display display)
        : this(model, manufacturer, price, owner)
    {
        this.battery = battery;
        this.display = display;
    }

      }
```

---

BATTERY

```
public enum BatteryType             // Is this suppose to be here or inside the class?
{
    LiIon, LiPo, NiMH, NiCd
}

class Battery
{
    //battery characteristics
    private string model;
    private int hoursIdle;
    private int hoursTalk;
    private BatteryType batteryType = new BatteryType();

}
```

======
DISPLAY

```
class Display
{
    //display characteristics
    private double size;
    private int numberOfColors;

    // CONSTRUCTORS:
    public Display(double size, int numberOfColors)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.numberOfColors = numberOfColors;
    }
}
```

====MAIN:

```
   class GSMTest
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
        GSM myGSM = new GSM("Sony ERcs", "Sony ERRR", 124.56m, "Pesho", BatteryType.LiPo, 12.3); 
        // I can't create this object. Argument5: cannont convert from GSM.BatteryType to GSM.Battery. What gives!?
        // Display has 2 fields. I have an instance of it in GSM. Yet I don't know how to set it here so I can create myGSM

    }
```

## }

P.S. They're all from the same namespace; And there's a constructor for class Battery as well. Forgot to include it, don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: We're not going to analyze your full code. Create a small sample that reproduces the problem you're encountering, and describe the problem in one question for each problem, sharing your research for that specific problem.

Comment: Thanks! I took care of it.

Comment: Your GSM constructor expects an instance of a Battery class, not an enum of type BatteryType. You should create an instance of a Battery and pass the reference to this instance in the constructor call. The same happens for the Display parameter. You need an instance of Display to pass there not a floating number

Comment: I added the Battery and Display instances in the main class and it worked. But I already had them in the GSM class. And I want them to work from there. So I can keep the main clean and simple.

Comment: Got it! I had to initiate new objects Battery and Display in the GSM constructor. Although this is kinda obscure and crazy for me. New object as a parameter in a constructor!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with regards to embedding an `enum` inside a `class`, it's best to think of `enum` as a special kind of `class` (which, under the hood, it is). In this way, only embed an `enum` in similar situations when you would create a [nested `class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx).

The issues that arise with syntax when doing this are simple verbosity - nothing can refer to the embedded type from outside the outer type without referencing the outer type explicitly. Since [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) can only be applied to namespaces (other than aliases) it won't shorten the syntax without extra work, so consider whether to maker more sense for an external caller to refer to `BatteryType` in code as

```
var t = Battery.BatteryType.LiIon
```

or

```
var t = BatteryType.NiCd
```

As for referring to a type within a constructor, when a constructor takes an object of a certain type, you must pass an object of that type or derived from it. Thus, it may be useful to create other variables

```
Battery bat = new Battery();
Display disp = new Display(12.3, 256);
GSM myGSM = new GSM("Sony ERcs", "Sony ERRR", 124.56m, "Pesho", bat, disp);
```

In addition, you can nest calls to `new` just as with any other call

```
GSM myGSM = new GSM(
    "Sony ERcs",
    "Sony ERRR",
    124.56m,
    "Pesho",
    new Battery(),
    new Display(12.3, 256));
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. :)
I think I understood the enum idea. Basically, if it's inside a class, and I need it some place else, I'll need to reference it by <class Name>.<data type>.<data element or variable>.
 And there's no right or wrong. Just a matter of preference.